# javascriptを用いて作成したタイマーの時間をdjangoで記録することは可能ですか

Tags: python, javascript, django

#試したいこと
django初学者のものです
javascriptを用いて作成したタイマー
(今回参考にしたいタイマーの全体コードhttps://dev.to/gspteck/create-a-stopwatch-in-javascript-2mak)
のstopボタンを押したときに，押した時点での時間をdjangoで記録し管理することは可能でしょうか。もし可能であれば詳細の書かれた参考サイトなども教えていただけると幸いです。サイトは英語のものでも構いません

Comment: JSでデータを取得し、AJAXでDJANGOに送信することができます

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。その方法で実装してみようと思います